# Devise ldap authenticatable returns 401 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ldap

I am making some application in rails in which user needs to be log-in first to see the content. I used `devise` and `ldap_devise_authenticatable` to make user log-in through existing LDAP account.

However, when I tried to log in with my account into my application then `log-in failure occurs(401 error unauthorized)` even though I already have account on ldap.

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.blackfistsecurity.com/2011/12/rails-authentication-using-devise-and_27.html)

And following is the screenshot of my ldap server page:
[image]

I know the problem is in my ldap configuration file. How can i configure it properly so that my application send correct string to ldap server like in above screenshot

Code of my ldap.yml is as follows:

```
authorizations: &AUTHORIZATIONS
  group_base: ou=groups,dc=test,dc=com
  required_groups:
    - cn=admins,ou=groups,dc=test,dc=com
    - cn=users,ou=groups,dc=test,dc=com
    - ["moreMembers", "cn=users,ou=groups,dc=test,dc=com"]
  require_attribute:
    objectClass: inetOrgPerson
    authorizationRole: postsAdmin

## Environment

development:
  host: 172.16.100.6
  port: 389
  attribute: cn
  base: ou=People,dc=iitj,dc=ac,dc=in
  #admin_user: cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com
  #admin_password: admin_password
  ssl: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting attribute: sAMAccountName?
Also you need to set admin_ser and admin_password to match the credentials of the account you have in LDAP.